# Why is coldfusion not storing sessions in the database

Tags: mysql, database, session, coldfusion

I have set coldfusion to store sessions in the database, but the table is blank.  I have the datasource configured to retrieve CLOB.  I'm using CF7, MySQL Connector.  Why isn't it working? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have most likely set it to store CLIENT variables in the database.  Session variables are always stored in memory.  Client variables can be stored in the registry (on Windows), a cookie on the client machine, or in a database.

EDIT:

[Link to Documentation for ColdFusion 7 Client Variables](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?href=00001707.htm)